# Dropzone hangs on files larger than 1mb

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js in Meteor along with CollectionFS. I used it both as a package and standalone. Each time I did, everything works great except when I try to upload files over 1mb (It seems like that is the size limit at least) the progress bar just hangs and the "complete" callback never gets called. I've tried a lot of the Dropzone options and nothing seems to resolve it. This is what I have:

Javascript:

```
Template.projectsNew.rendered = ->
   Meteor.dropzone = new Dropzone '#dropzone',
      url: '/'
      maxFilesize: 5
      maxFiles: 50
      maxThumbnailSize: 5
      init: ->
         @on 'complete', (file) ->
            Files.insert file, (error, fileObject) ->
               if error
                  console.log "Error: #{error}"
               else
                  uploadedFileIds = Session.get 'uploadedFileIds'
                  uploadedFileIds.push fileObject._id
                  Session.set 'uploadedFileIds', uploadedFileIds
```

HTML:

```
 fieldset
    legend Documents

    #dropzone.dropzone
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone else got stuck with this... I had the same problem, and got just absolutely stuck... finally worked it out after like 4+ hours of hitting walls.

so turns out dropzone loads and complete a post request, and i guess that's not how collectionFS or meteor handles it ... anyhoo I'm too beginner to understand all that.

Long story short, **the complete will never fire within dropzone**, but you can catch the file upon 'accept', which is an option specification of dropzone, instead of an event.

So I worked around it and make the collectionFS image store happens in the accept options, and just remove the icon afterward, which looks perfectly fine and works perfect as well!

```html
<form action="#" class="dropzone" id="dropzone"></form>
```

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
  accept(file) {
    if (file.status == 'added') {

      var newFile = new FS.File(file);

      Images.insert(newFile, function (error, fileObj) {
        if (error) {
          ...
        }
          else {
            ...
          }

            // clear out dropzone
            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
          }
        });
      }
    }
});
```

If anyone need some extra help with this particular issue, please leave a comment or get in touch, I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Stephen if this works I will seriously take you out to lunch if/when you are ever in Utah. I'll try it out this afternoon. Thank you so much for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the [CollectionFS package](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages). One of its features is that it breaks files into pieces when uploading them to any number of storage options (gridFS, S3, etc...)

Comment: Hi @Michel. I'm actually using CollectionFS as well. I'm just using Dropzone as the front end, which then interfaces with CollectionFS.

Comment: Interesting. I started my project using DropZone but then dropped it and wrote my own event handler that ties to CollectionFS. It works well for very large files however I'm doing my own chunking before passing chunks to CollectionFS. To do this I use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Comment: Oh cool. I'm really only using Dropzone because of the UI interaction. Maybe I could integrate that with FileReader.